# insert sequence from 0000000 to nnnnnnn

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

I have a query like below to insert number id.

```
INSERT INTO tb_number(number_id,number_value) VALUES 
(concat('T', currval('number_sequence')),1)
```

How do i change the number_id into format Tnnnnnnn (T and follow of 7 digits of number_sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function [`LPAD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-string.html) for embedding value to a string value from the left.

```
INSERT INTO tb_number(number_id,number_value) VALUES 
(concat('T', LPAD(CAST(currval('number_sequence') as text), 7, '0')),1)
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. It said "function lped(bigint, integer, unknown) does not exist"

Comment: Sorry it should be LPAD, I wrote it wrong, correcting now.

Comment: Thanks for comment. It said "function lpad(bigint, integer, unknown) does not exist" . what is the version of postgresql supported?

Comment: I think the problem is due to bigint in the first argument of LPAD. Could you try the new version above with casting (`cast(...)`)? See in the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly:

```
INSERT INTO tb_number(number_id,number_value)
    VALUES ('T' || to_char(currval('number_sequence'), 'FM0000000'), 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can format the sequence value with

```
to_char(currval('number_sequence'), 'TFM0000000')
```